# foreach loop does not execute

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to store values to array using foreach loop, here is my code

```
public function priceRegulation(){
        $prices = Price::where('hotel_id', $this->id);

        $lowerPrices = [];

        if($prices->count() > 0){
            foreach ($prices as $price) {
                
                    $lowerPrices[] = $price;
                
            }

            if(sizeof($lowerPrices) < 1){
                return false;
            } else{
                return true;
            }
        } else{
            return 'empty';
        }
    }
```

I have also tried setting $lowerPrices to 0 (int type) and increment it through foreach, but result was the same variable remaind at 0. I have tested if statements and they work fine. The problem is with foreach it basically does nothing. I am using Laravel Framework.
Any help is welcome!
Regards

Comment: I don't think so, since first if statement works, I see that by return value. It returns 'empty' correctly, but it returns false for where it should return false and true. So basically array always has 0 elements

Comment: `$prices` is a Query Builder, it isn't the result of anything; you need to get the result of the query with `get` or the likes ... calling `count()` there is calling `count` on the builder (doing a count query) not calling `count` on a Collection (result) ... a Query Builder doesn't have public properties to iterate (which is what happens when you try to iterate a random object) so the loop doesn't run

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
 $prices = Price::where('hotel_id', $this->id);
```

You aren't fetching the data, change it to:

```
$prices = Price::where('hotel_id', $this->id)->get();
```

Comment: I tried it, it is the same. I think that is not the problem, since the first if statemnt works fine. It counts fine

Comment: what's the value of $this->id ?

Comment: It holds value of hotel id

Comment: Check if it's null or empty var_dump($this->id). What's it giving ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$prices = Price::where('hotel_id', $this->id)->get();
```

Do this you will get the data.

Comment: I tried it, it is the same. I think that is not the problem, since the first if statemnt works fine. It counts fine

Answer (score 0):

```
public function priceRegulation(){
        $prices = Price::where('hotel_id', $this->id)->get();

        $lowerPrices = [];
        // dd($prices); check if your $prices is not 0
        if($prices->count() > 0){
            foreach ($prices as $price) {
                
                    array_push($lowerPrices, $price);
                
            }

            if(sizeof($lowerPrices) < 1){
                return false;
            } else{
                return true;
            }
        } else{
            return 'empty';
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you change? What was the problem? Always add some explanation instead of just dumping code

Comment: i added ```get();``` to the  ```Price::where()```

Answer (score 0):

You did not use get() function

```
$prices = Price::where('hotel_id', $this->id)->get();
```

but why you use $this->id because in the funcation you are not use request to get data.

I think it will helps you.